# Facebook SDK Integration

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Could someone post some example code for the Facebook authorize code for android.  I've been at it for a while and I can't get it to work.

```
    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    facebook.authorize(this, new LoginDialogListener());
```

That's what I have.

Thanks

Comment: Describe the error, what else did you try so far etc. Also @downvoter please leave comment.

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  All I'm getting is the facebook webview shows up for a second then it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK from GitHub and look at the sample app, it contains everything you need to get started and totally answers this question.

Comment: specifically, look at the sample app in the "simple" folder and then look at the LoginButton class to see how it handles the event for login click and the Facebook response handling